# pk-client-error-quark and apt-get update errors

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository

If I try to change the server from which the "Software & Updates" app downloads the updates from, I get the following error:

```
pk-client-error-quark
E: archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal
InRelease is not (yet) available (impossible connecting to archive.canonical.com:443 (91.189.91.15) - connection refused
```

Also `sudo apt-get update` returns some errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease           
Err:1 https://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:443 (91.189.91.15). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Hit:3 https://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 https://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 https://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:6 https://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.canonical.com:443 (91.189.91.15). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is wrong with it? I have traveled through a few countries and this might have messed up the repositories perhaps.

Additional info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

Comment: Hello. Here is the official list of all mirrors.  Check and see if you are pointing to one of them. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors What version of Ubuntu are you using? Why are you trying to connect to archive?

Comment: @David 20.04.4. What archive? you mean the `archive.canonical.com/`? Even if I change the server as one of those official ones, e.g., `ubuntu.mirror.garr.it` I still receive errors, even when updating the cache from the "Software & Updates" app.

Comment: Get rid of the Microsoft reference in the sources list. I am guessing its a PPA? From your question. <Err:1 https://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu> I tried that path in a browser it does not work. Where is this coming from?

Comment: Please, how? I am not sure what you are referring to

Comment: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/ubuntu-sources-list-editing-guide/#:~:text=To%20start%2C%20open%20up%20your,by%20using%20the%20command%20below.&text=Once%20inside%20of%20the%20Nano,changes%20to%20Ubuntu%20with%20update.

Comment: I am Ctrl+F "Microsoft" in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and can't find any

Comment: It is there in your post. <Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease  >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135601/discussion-between-py-ser-and-david).

Comment: I removed it from "Other software" tab in the "Software&Updates" app, but when I close the app it should update, yet it returns the same error as before

Comment: Readers: Before getting into this, I suggest you review some additional chat history [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135598/optimize-thermal-daemon)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I had the same problem, and it was solved without issues for me. In my case it appeared as "restriced" but once I added the mirrored on the source.list, everything got fixed

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem (or at least part of it) was that some of the officially supported mirrors listed on the page [of the Ubuntu archive mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) really don't have Focal Fossa version release.

I have edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` listing only those mirrors that have the release for sure (after I personally checked), and then I `sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt upgrade`. I think I'll need to add other (more updated) mirrors also, but for now the errors are gone:

```
$ sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt upgrade
Hit:1 https://ubuntu.mirror.garr.it/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Reading package lists... Done                            
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```